# How can I enable mouse wheel scroll in 'less' in lxterminal?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

In Lubuntu 11.10, when I use the 'less' pager in lxterminal, the mouse scroll wheel has no effect. In gnome-terminal, it scrolls the text up or down when viewing a file with 'less'.

Is there anyway to enable this functionality in lxterminal?

Comment: The same issue happens with all VTE-based terminals in ubuntu. The reason seems to be ubuntu-specific patches to the libvte package that broke all other terminal implementations. I gave up on the matter after clicking 'me too' on a bug report for xfce4-terminal and patching it for three releases in a row.

Comment: @aquaherd: Thanks for the info. Sounds like you've had a lot of experience with this issue. I'll file a bug report against lxterminal at launchpad and see what happens.

Comment: Here's a link to the bug report for this issue: [bug #881433](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxterminal/+bug/881433).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!